# Property Injection in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am relatively new to working with DI containers and have hit a bit of a roadblock.

SimpleInjector has a method with the following signature:

```
Container.RegisterInitializer<TService>(Action<TService>)
```

In our code base we do use it like this:

```
// this is a property injection of the abstract file system
container.RegisterInitializer<IFileSystemInjection>(
    fs => fs.FileSystem = new FileSystem());
```

I am wondering how I would achieve the same using the IServiceCollection parameter in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs class.  So far I have been able to register all my types using the services.AddTransient();  but I am not sure how what the equivalent simpleinjector.RegisterInitializer is within the IServiceCollection.

Comment: Microsoft's MS.DI container does not support property injection. What you want, can't easily be achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use the factory overload(s) of `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped`, and `AddTransient`. I'm not sure what scope `IFileSystemInjection` should be in, but it *sounds* like something that could be a singleton. If not, change the method you call appropriately:

```
service.AddSingleton<IFileSystemInjection>(p =>
{
    var fs = new FileSystemInjection();
    fs.FileSystem = new FileSystem();
});
```

In short, if you provide a factory, then you're responsible for the entire object initialization, hence the `new FileSystemInjection()`, which I'm subbing as the actual implementation of `IFileSystemInjection` your using.

If that implementation has dependencies that need to be injected in order to create it, you can pull those from `p`, which is an instance of `IServiceProvider`:

```
var myDep = p.GetRequiredService<MyDep>();
var fs = new FileSystemImplementation(myDep);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am still getting a null object at runtime where that dependency is required. But at least the syntax seems to have put me on the right path now.

Comment: Thank you, with yours and Stevens input I was able to get it working. I did convert the property injection into constructor injection as Steven mentioned the difficulty in doing property injection with MS.DI.